# Not accessible 'Side' field in DocuSign Rooms API

Tags: docusignapi

There is a field named ['Side' (transactionSide)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuhnJ.png) in DocuSign room UI.
It has one of these values: buy, sell, listbuy, refi.
Unfortunately, I cannot get this field by using API endpoints:

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/rooms/{roomId}

GET /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/rooms/{roomId}/field_data
```

1. Is there a way to get this field by using API?
2. Can I update this field using update field data endpoint (PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/rooms/{roomId}/field_data) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called `transactionSideId` in the JSON.

Did you know we also have SDKs for the Rooms API? you can use them in C#, Java, Node, PHP, Python and Ruby. That should help find properties names I would think...
(here is a [recent blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-inviting-someone-to-docusign-room) with some examples)

**UPDATE:**
As a workaround, Room’s side is defined by Room Owner’s side. So to identify RoomSide user would need to call following endpoint:

```
/v2/accounts/{accountId}/rooms/{roomId}/users
```

If calling user knows who the owner of the room is, **transactionSideId** defined for that user, i.e. the Room Owner is Room’s transactionSide. Unfortunately, I didn’t see a way to identify Room Owner’s userId.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need this field `transactionSideId` when I GET existing room, not create a room. I can't find this field when I do `GetRoom` or `GetRoomFieldData` requests.
Is there a way to get transactionSideId field using API?

Comment: How can I detect which side this room is?

Comment: hmmm, so you are saying get field data doesn't return it? I'd have to ask the Rooms API experts on this.

Comment: Exactly. There is no full description of response for field data request in API documentation, so I cannot be sure if this field should be returned.

Comment: @Volodymyr it appears this is not available right now. I've filed a ticke to get this added. Not sure how long that would take. I'll update you.

Comment: There's a workaround that I found. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That's make sense. But, as you mentioned, I cannot find room's owner from this users. 
So the questions for now are:
1) How can I identify room's owner?
2) Does it mean that transactionSideId will be different for different users?

Comment: 3) A room has createdByUserId field. Is a creator of a room must be also the owner of this room?

Comment: 3) UPD: looks like not. I can create a room and set ownership to another user.